# Alternative to complex for loop to improve performance

Tags: r, performance, loops, for-loop

The following code uses a 20x1 data frame, to check on every row if any of the 6 rows below (i.e. rows i+1 to i+7) is greater than 3 rows further below by 2 points (e.g. i+1 - i+4 > 2). If true, a 1 is recorded on newly created Signal column.

For example, for row one, it checks if:

- row 2 > row 5 + 2 OR
- row 3 > row 6 + 2 OR

...

- row 7 > row 10 + 2

If possible, I would like to find an alternative approach to the for loop. I'm running this template code on a large database, and the loop can take hours. Please note the code for the loop is a bit complex to avoid the loop from going out of boundaries. Many thanks @Gregor for his massive help on putting this together.

```
#Data
df <- data.frame(Price = c( 1221, 1220, 1220, 1217, 1216,  1218 , 1216, 1216, 1217, 1220, 1219, 1218, 1220, 1216, 1217, 1218, 1218, 1207, 1206, 1205))

#Inputs
Window = 6                # check up to this far below current row
IndexDifference = 3       # check row against another this far down
ValueDifference = 2       # for difference at least this big

#Define loop boundaries 
base_rows = 1:(nrow(df) - IndexDifference)  # can't check more than this
candidate_max = pmin(base_rows + Window, nrow(df) - IndexDifference) # for a given base row, this is the maximum row to start checking against

#Make Signal variable
df$Signal = rep(NA, nrow(df)) #pre-allocate variable
for (i in seq_along(base_rows)) {
  df$Signal[i] = as.numeric(
    any(
      df$Price[(i + 1):candidate_max[i]] - 
        df$Price[((i + 1):candidate_max[i]) + IndexDifference] > ValueDifference))}
```

Comment: I should be more efficient to avoid `[.data.frame` and `[<-.data.frame` if you, just, have a "Signal" and a "Price" vector. E.g. compare assigning to a single column "data.frame" in contrast to a simple vector: `x1 = data.frame(col1 = integer(1e5)); x2 = integer(1e5); system.time( for(i in seq_len(nrow(x1))) x1$col1[i] = 1L ); system.time( for(i in seq_along(x2)) x2[i] = 1L )`

Comment: Thank you Alexis. I have dozens of columns. This is a simplified example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution to this problem is to build two matrices of lagged columns and subtract one from the other. This makes use of vectorisation in R and should be fast.

```
df0 <- cbind(df$Price[-(1)][1:nrow(df)], sapply(2:Window, function(i)df$Price[-(1:i)][1:nrow(df)]))
df1 <- sapply((IndexDifference+1):(IndexDifference+Window), function(i)df$Price[-(1:i)][1:nrow(df)])  
df$Signal <- as.numeric(apply((df0 - df1) > ValueDifference, 1, any, na.rm = TRUE))
df$Signal
```

Note, this does not give exactly the same result as your code, probably because when

```
i = 17
(i + 1):candidate_max[i]
```

evaluates as `c(18, 17)` which is probably not what you want.

Comment: As running this on thousands of rows, not a problem losing one data point at the end. This works perfect, many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit late, but in case it's useful.

I agree with @alexis_laz that more comparisons are being computed than necessary. I think that idea can be taken an step further though, because if `any` is applied in a rolling fashion, that also carries unnecessary calculations.

The key is that a given row is always compared to another specific row (3 below in your example). Once we know whether the equivalence holds for that row, any other rows that contain it within the given window should be given the value of 1 (TRUE).

The useful shortcut here is that if the equivalence holds for row `j` and that makes row `i` TRUE, and row `j` is also within the window of row `i+1`, then `i+1` is also TRUE (without needing to know the status of the other points in the window). What I'm getting at is that we don't need to determine the `any` for each row's window. If we know how many TRUEs there are in row `i`'s window, for row `i+1` we just need to determine whether the point leaving the window was TRUE and whether the point entering the window is TRUE. Essentially we're filtering the vector with a box of `Window`-width, and then just checking which entries have at least one TRUE value in their window (this could be all done in a single pass, but let's ignore that since the extra time is not significant).

Using a rolling sum, we can efficiently calculate this just by having a running tally, and including/removing the points entering/leaving the window. This is where @alexis_laz's observation comes in: the status of the points entering/leaving can be precalculated.

To make things more concrete, here's some code. First, let me copy over your original loop, @Richard Telford's answer, and @alexis_laz's answer and wrap them into functions (with slight re-writes mainly for personal convenience and so the output format matches, and hopefully without adding any bugs):

```
f_G <- function(x, window, idiff, valdiff){
  base_rows = 1:(NROW(x) - idiff - 1)  # can't check more than this
candidate_max = pmin(base_rows + window, NROW(x) - idiff) # maximum row to start checking against
  out = rep(0, NROW(x)) #pre-allocate variable
  for (i in seq_along(base_rows)) {
    out[i] = as.numeric(any(x[(i + 1):candidate_max[i]]
           - x[((i + 1):candidate_max[i]) + idiff] > valdiff))}
  return(out)
}

f_RT <- function(x, window, idiff, valdiff){
  x0 <- cbind(x[-(1)][1:NROW(x)], sapply(2:window,
                                        function(i)x[-(1:i)][1:NROW(x)]))
  x1 <- sapply((idiff+1):(idiff+window),
              function(i)x[-(1:i)][1:NROW(x)])
  out <- as.numeric(apply((x0 - x1) > valdiff, 1, any, na.rm = TRUE))
  return(out)
}

f_AL <- function(x, window, idiff, valdiff){
  check = (x[2:(NROW(x) - idiff)] - x[(2 + idiff):NROW(x)]) > valdiff
  check <- c(check, rep(FALSE, idiff+1))
  out <- as.integer(sapply(seq_along(check),
                      function(i) any(check[i:min(length(check), (i + (window - 1)))])))
  return(out)
}
```

Then here are two functions to calculate the rolling sum I described above, over a vector with the precalculated differences (like @alexis_laz suggested). The first uses the [`filter`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/stats/filter) function, while the second one uses [`roll_sum`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/RcppRoll/docs/roll_sum) from the [RcppRoll](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppRoll/index.html) package.

```
f_filt <- function(x, window, idiff, valdiff){
  ## calculate idiff differences once
  check = as.integer((x[2:(NROW(x) - idiff)] - x[(2 + idiff):NROW(x)]) > valdiff)
  ## extend series to filter
  check <- c(check, rep(0, window+idiff))
  ## reverse series due to filter using "past" values
  ffilt <- rev(filter(rev(check), rep(1, window), sides=1))
  ## check if at least one
  out <- ifelse(na.omit(ffilt) > 0, 1, 0)
  return(out)
}

library(RcppRoll)
f_roll <- function(x, window, idiff, valdiff){
  ## calculate idiff differences once
  check = as.integer((x[2:(NROW(x) - idiff)] - x[(2 + idiff):NROW(x)]) > valdiff)
  ## extend series to filter
  check <- c(check, rep(0, window+idiff))
  ## rolling window sum
  froll <- roll_sum(check, n=window, align="right")
  out <- ifelse(froll > 0, 1, 0)
  return(out)
}
```

As a quick check, we can test that all functions give the same answers:

```
f_G(df$Price, Window, IndexDifference, ValueDifference)
# 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
f_RT(df$Price, Window, IndexDifference, ValueDifference)
# 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
f_AL(df$Price, Window, IndexDifference, ValueDifference)
# 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
f_filt(df$Price, Window, IndexDifference, ValueDifference)
# 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
f_roll(df$Price, Window, IndexDifference, ValueDifference)
# 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
```

Now let's benchmark them. I'll also increase the number of rows to test.

```
library(microbenchmark)
w <- Window
idiff <- IndexDifference
vdiff <- ValueDifference

df2 <- rep(df$Price, 5000) #100,000 entries
microbenchmark(f_G(df2, w, idiff, vdiff),
               f_RT(df2, w, idiff, vdiff),
               f_AL(df2, w, idiff, vdiff),
               f_filt(df2, w, idiff, vdiff),
               f_roll(df2, w, idiff, vdiff)
               )
Unit: milliseconds
                         expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval   cld
    f_G(df2, w, idiff, vdiff) 395.80227 412.05120 419.88554 413.55551 417.84907 479.47306   100     e
   f_RT(df2, w, idiff, vdiff) 154.43919 192.99473 193.10029 195.61031 197.95933 236.27244   100   c  
   f_AL(df2, w, idiff, vdiff) 233.30237 244.01664 249.75449 245.07001 248.51249 319.04956   100    d 
 f_filt(df2, w, idiff, vdiff)  21.53997  22.51582  25.38218  22.59477  23.56873  63.48320   100  b   
 f_roll(df2, w, idiff, vdiff)  14.26333  14.35543  16.99302  15.24879  15.45127  55.49886   100 a
```

Finally, we see that we get a pretty nice speed boost doing this. The other neat thing about approaching it this way, is that it remains just as efficient regardless of the window size (in particular, directly doing the rolling sum; using `filter` does slow down a bit, although it's still pretty quick).

```
w <- 25 #Window
df3 <- rep(df$Price, 5000) #100,000 entries
microbenchmark(f_G(df3, w, idiff, vdiff),
               f_RT(df3, w, idiff, vdiff),
               f_AL(df3, w, idiff, vdiff),
               f_filt(df3, w, idiff, vdiff),
               f_roll(df3, w, idiff, vdiff)
               )
Unit: milliseconds
                         expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval   cld
    f_G(df3, w, idiff, vdiff) 487.65798 516.67700 537.54019 541.34459 551.52128 592.05720   100     e
   f_RT(df3, w, idiff, vdiff) 328.44934 366.76176 389.08534 401.39053 409.49376 518.94535   100    d 
   f_AL(df3, w, idiff, vdiff) 240.99006 258.66045 263.21317 260.09258 263.75917 319.02493   100   c  
 f_filt(df3, w, idiff, vdiff)  37.32291  37.41098  38.97167  37.47234  38.40989  79.51684   100  b   
 f_roll(df3, w, idiff, vdiff)  15.49264  15.52950  15.86283  15.55252  15.62852  19.77415   100 a
```

Answer (score 1):

In your loop, most `Price[i] - Price[i + IndexDifference] > ValueDifference` are computed more than once; in this case (code at the end) most comparisons are made 6 times:

```
#    [i]  [i + IndexDifference]  [times calculated]   
#    Var1 Var2 Freq
#70     2    5    1
#88     3    6    2
#106    4    7    3
#124    5    8    4
#142    6    9    5
#160    7   10    6
#178    8   11    6
#196    9   12    6
#214   10   13    6
#232   11   14    6
#250   12   15    6
#268   13   16    6
#286   14   17    6
#304   15   18    6
#322   16   19    6
#340   17   20    6
```

Also, I guess, it's not just the repeated computations per se, but the repetitive assigning (and subsetting) to "data.frame"s.

Instead you could compute the differences and the comparisons once:

```
tmp = (df$Price[2:(nrow(df) - IndexDifference)] - 
      df$Price[(2 + IndexDifference):nrow(df)]) > ValueDifference
```

And apply, in rolling fashion, `any` (taking into notice your comment about not going out of bounds):

```
as.integer(sapply(seq_along(tmp), 
                  function(i) any(tmp[i:min(length(tmp), (i + (Window - 1)))])))
#[1] 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
                #and 4 values are left (rows 17:20 that cannot be 
                #calculated based on the conditions) to be added as `NA`
```

*Tabulation of comparisons:*

```
#re-calculcated your 'base_rows' to not include row 17 as it exceeds tha 'IndexDifference'
base_rows = 1:(nrow(df) - IndexDifference - 1L)  
candidate_max = pmin(base_rows + Window, nrow(df) - IndexDifference) 

#set-up the tabulations for each comparison     
table_diffs = matrix(0L, 
                     base_rows[length(base_rows)] + 1L,
                     candidate_max[length(candidate_max)] + IndexDifference)
for(i in seq_along(base_rows)) { 
    ij = cbind((i + 1):candidate_max[i], ((i + 1):candidate_max[i]) + IndexDifference)
    table_diffs[ij] = table_diffs[ij] + 1L
}   
#format
subset(transform(as.data.frame(as.table(table_diffs)), 
                 Var1 = as.integer(Var1), 
                 Var2 = as.integer(Var2)), 
       Freq != 0L)
```

Comment: Thanks very much Alexis for this! Have chosen @Richard Telford's response as answer to the question as both give same results yet his is slightly faster (tested both).